# How to shut down a golang service safely after receiving parameters - Best practices

Tags: go, service, parameters, shutdown

I have been implementing server using golang. I need to shutdown my server after receiving the expected parameter 'code'. Before shutting down the sever I need to redirect to a another web page. I have implemented as give below. This code is working. I need to know whether it is the best way of doing it ? Your suggestions are appreciated..

```
func main() {
    var code string
    const port  int = 8888
    httpPortString := ":" + strconv.Itoa(port)
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    fmt.Printf("Http Server initialized on Port %s", httpPortString)
    server := http.Server{Addr: httpPortString, Handler: mux}
    var timer *time.Timer
    mux.HandleFunc("/auth", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        err := r.ParseForm()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error parsing the code: %s", err)
        }
        code = r.Form.Get("code")
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error occurred while establishing the server: %s", err)
        }
        http.Redirect(w, r, "https://cloud.google.com/sdk/auth_success", http.StatusMovedPermanently)

        timer = time.NewTimer(2 * time.Second)
        go func() {
            <-timer.C
            server.Shutdown(context.Background())
        }()
    })
    if err := server.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        fmt.Printf("Error while establishing the service: %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Finished executing the the service")

}
```

Thank you ..!

Comment: No need to sleep. After http.Redirect returns, the response has been written and will arrive at the client eventually (assuming no network failure, if course).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing here is that if I don't sleep the request, the server shut downs before the redirect. So I had to add the timer. I need to know whether there are better ways of doing this since I feel that this is not the best way to achieve this task.

Comment: @Tharindu I've experienced similar behavior. This is a chicken-egg situation. A http response is only flushed to the client on handler-function return - so shutting down the server within the handler means there is no deterministic way to ensure one happens before the other. Yes, a sleep "works" - but we know it's not a guarantee.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot about the automatic flush. What happens if you call [w.Flush](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Flusher) (requires type assertion) before shutting down the server? Does that work?

Comment: @Peter is a flush enough in all cases? In this case it's a redirect with a 301 status code. But what happens if no status is set - and one expects an implicit 200 status code header to be written. Would a flush trigger that mechanism? I'm thinking one would have to explicitly write a 200 header first.

Comment: @colminator, as far as I can tell Flush is not required to call WriteHeader, but it's up to the implementation. However, reading [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Flusher) again it says "Note that even for ResponseWriters that support Flush, if the client is connected through an HTTP proxy, the buffered data may not reach the client until the response completes." So closing the server directly in the handler is indeed unreliable.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Shutdown shows a more controlled way to shutdown and wait - I've update the answer to include waiting for the shutdown operation to complete and all connects have been processed.

Comment: The flush worked for me.. Thanks ..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @Peter flushing suggestion and ideas from the example cited [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Shutdown):

```
f, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
if !ok {
    http.Error(w, "no flush support", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}   

http.Redirect(w, r, "https://cloud.google.com/sdk/auth_success", http.StatusSeeOther)

f.Flush() // <-- ensures client gets all writes
          // this is done implicitly on http handler returns, but...
          // we're shutting down the server now!

go func() {
    server.Shutdown(context.Background())
    close(idleConnsClosed)
}()
```

See full playground version for `idleConnsClosed` setup/cleanup: https://play.golang.org/p/UBmLfyhKT0B

---

P.S. Don't use `http.StatusMovedPermanently` unless you really want users never to use the source URL again. Users' browsers will cache this (301) code - and not hit your server - which may not be what you want. If you want temporary redirects use `http.StatusSeeOther` (code 303).